# Event markers on line charts

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Has anyone managed to get text based event markets on a line chart? I've got a line graph and I want to display text on specific dates on the line chart.

See below link as an example
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gevgeny/highcharts-flags-grouping/master/demo/demo.png

Comment: It may help if you post some example data (as text) and an image of what you want to accomplish as an example.

Comment: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gevgeny/highcharts-flags-grouping/master/demo/demo.png

Comment: Like the above link provided. But having a small amount of text instead of the numbers.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the image?

Answer (score 0):

If the text you want to display is in your dataset then this is simple.

As an example I created a sample dataset using the following Query to generate some simple values

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(X int, Y int, comment varchar(10))

INSERT INTO @t VALUES
(1, 1, 'One-One'),
(2, 2, 'Two-Two'),
(3, 1, 'Three-One'),
(4, 4, 'Four-Four'),
(5, 6, 'Five-Six'),
(6, 3, 'Six-Three')

SELECT * FROM @t
```

I then added a simple line chart pointing to this dataset.
Set the chart up as with `Y` as the values and `X` as the category group, this gives us a simple line as expected.

[image]

I then right-clicked the series line and switched on data labels

[image]

Finally, with the series line selected, go to the properties window and expand the 'Label' group, then set the 'Label' property to, in my case, `=Fields!comment.Value`

[image]

This gives use the following output.

[image]

Hope that helps.

Comment: I was actually trying something similar but couldn't find it. This should help. Will give it a go.